# Getting separate characters from a java Scanner

Tags: java

In Java's Scanner class, why does the syntax `nextChar()` not exist, and is there a command would do something similar with out using the `String` variable?

Answer (score 5):

Two solutions:

- use `toCharArray()`: this will return a `char[]` over which you can use a foreach loop;
- use the string length in combination with `.charAt()`.

Comment: thanks, this has given me a brilliant idea, i had forgotten i could use .charAt() to get any letter from the whole string

Answer (score 2):

Java's Scanner class operates on tokens, complete units of output.  This is usually complete words, lines of text, numbers (integers, doubles, floats, etc).  If you want to read individual characters, you should use BufferedReader in a construct like this

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Replacing `System.in` with whatever input you're using for Scanner.  Then use `char c = (char)in.read()` to read the next character from the input.

Comment: would i have to use a different java util for that? or can i just use it with just            import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: you'll need additional imports.  Easiest way to go is to add `import java.io.*`

Answer (score 2):

If you want char level access you can go a level below and simply use the InputStream interface :

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        while (true)
        {
            char c = (char)System.in.read();
            System.out.println("[" + c + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not always the case though, right?  If I send, for instance, a multi-byte UTF-8 character into System.in, will it be properly parsed by the `read` call, which only returns a single byte?  This is why a BufferedReader is prefered.

Comment: this works, although when you run it in cmd it puts alternating brackets in 3 lines between each char.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.next(“.{1,}”);
```

So, you can use `Scanner#next()` method and pass regular expression which consumes only one char as a parameter.
You can use an example above.